# Get WooCommerce featured products in a WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I updated WooCommerce to version 3.0 but I can't show the featured products on my theme, I googled a while and get WC deleted the _feature and add this in taxonomy. But I don't understand so much how my theme get the featured products.

Here is the code of the wrong featured productcs.

```
$meta_query   = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'   => '_featured',
        'value' => 'yes'
    );

    $args = array(
        'post_type'           => 'product',
        'post_status'         => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'posts_per_page'      => $products,
        'orderby'             => $orderby,
        'order'               => $order == 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc',
        'meta_query'          => $meta_query
    );
```

And if you know where is the featured item in the DataBase. Thanks so much.

Comment: How are you trying to display the featured products? Are you trying to run a `WP_Query`? I can't tell what is happening in your code. Have you considered using the `[featured_products]` shortcode?

Comment: How I can use [featured_products] shortcode?

Comment: The theme itself made the shortcodes for the theme and these shortcode are the problem. This extract are part of the code.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Since Woocommerce 3, you have to use a **Tax Query** instead as **featured products** are now handled by `product_visibility` **custom taxonomy** for the term **`featured`**:

```
// The tax query
$tax_query[] = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
    'field'    => 'name',
    'terms'    => 'featured',
    'operator' => 'IN', // or 'NOT IN' to exclude feature products
);

// The query
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'           => 'product',
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page'      => $products,
    'orderby'             => $orderby,
    'order'               => $order == 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc',
    'tax_query'           => $tax_query // <===
) );
```

References:

- Official documentation [`WP_Query` Taxonomy Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)
- Source code [Woocommerce `WC_Shortcodes` `featured_products()` function](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Shortcodes.html#440-461)

> You could use [`wc_get_featured_product_ids()` function](http://wc_get_featured_product_ids()) to get the **featured product IDs array** but using a **tax query** in a `WP_Query` **is just fine** and the right way…

Related:

- [Woocommerce meta_query not working for featured products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49060029/woocommerce-meta-query-not-working-for-featured-products/49063172#49063172)
- [Show only featured products in Woocommerce shop page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345688/show-only-featured-products-in-woocommerce-shop-page/50346805#50346805)
- [Get featured products in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48848719/get-featured-products-in-woocommerce-3/48848989#48848989)

It should work.

Answer (score 16):

This is an old question, but you can use [wc_get_featured_product_ids()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_featured_product_ids.html) too:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'           => 'product',
    'posts_per_page'      => $products,
    'orderby'             => $orderby,
    'order'               => $order == 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc',
    'post__in'            => wc_get_featured_product_ids(),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Just discovered it here. I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, it works great! I don't understand why they moved from a postmeta to a taxonomy, makes no sense.

Answer (score 12):

You can now use wc_get_products with parameter featured set to true. See https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query

```
$args = array(
    'featured' => true,
);
$products = wc_get_products( $args );
```

For people looking for getting featured products by category then you can check my notes about this =>  https://jameshwartlopez.com/plugin/get-featured-products-of-a-category/

Answer (score 5):

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                    'field'    => 'name',
                    'terms'    => 'featured',
                ),
            ),
        );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
```