# Get featured products in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I want to add Featured products for upsell (or Recent Products OR Best Selling Products) in **New order** Email template. It works like Upsell with email marketing. How do I add it to woocommerce email template so that there is a section in the end of the email which shows my featured/Recent/best selling products. I tried using this code in my New order Email template but nothing works. I use all latest  version of wordpress n woocommerce.

```
$args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'product',  
    'meta_key' => '_featured',  
    'meta_value' => 'yes',  
    'posts_per_page' => 1  
);  

$featured_query = new WP_Query( $args );  

if ($featured_query->have_posts()) :   

    while ($featured_query->have_posts()) :   

        $featured_query->the_post();  

        $product = get_product( $featured_query->post->ID );  

        // Output product information here  

    endwhile;  

endif;  

wp_reset_query(); // Remember to reset
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Woocommerce 3, the products following properties:

- "featured",
- "stock status",
- "catalog visibility"
- "rating system"

are now stored like a post term under `'product_visibility'` **taxonomy**, for better performances. So old postmeta data doesn't work anymore.

To make your code working you need instead to make a `tax_query` this way:

```
function custom_featured_products(){

    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1 ,
        'tax_query' => array( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => 'featured',
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ) )
    ) );

    $featured_product_names = array();

    if ( $query->have_posts() ): while ( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();

            $product = wc_get_product( $query->post->ID );

            $featured_product_names[] = $product->get_title();

    endwhile; wp_reset_query();endif;

    // Testing output
    echo '<p>Featured products: ' . implode(', ', $featured_product_names) . '</p>';
}

// Displaying the featured products names in new order email notification
add_action ('woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'new_order_featured_products_display', 30, 4 );
function new_order_featured_products_display( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    // Only for "New Order" email notification
    if( 'new_order' != $email->id ) return;

    custom_featured_products(); // calling the featured products function output
}
```

This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).

Tested and works.

> Updated related to your comments…
>
> Added the code in a function that is called via a hooked function in "New order" email notification.
>
> To get the product image use: `$product->get_image( 'shop_thumbnail' );`
> To get the product link use : `$product->get_permalink();`

Comment: Thnk u very much, can I add this piece of code to theme-child/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php
will it work that way

Comment: thnk u , I want it in the end of New Order email template , like this - https://ibb.co/mKBk5n
it is like an Upsell strategy

Comment: Thnk u , definitely I m gonna accept n upvote after I get the solution. I tried to add the code in template but no luck, check this plz https://ibb.co/bLZYrS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165354/discussion-between-tanvir-and-loictheaztec).

Comment: Thnk u very much, it has added the Products well in Admin Email Template, I want to add it to customer New Order Template, so that only customer gets it. The code is working by the way.

Comment: @Tanvir I have added that in my answer at the end…

Comment: Thnk u very very much

Comment: how can get featured products using rest api v3 ? suggest me just api url please.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="products">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 12,
            'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                        'field'    => 'name',
                        'terms'    => 'featured',
                    ),
                ),
            );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
               echo '<p>'.get_the_title().'</p>';
            endwhile;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul><!--/.products-->
```