# Show only featured products in Woocommerce shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I want to display in default shop page from WooCommerce only featured products, nothing more...
It's there a solution to display in WooCommerce shop template only the featured products?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use this custom function hooked in `woocommerce_product_query_tax_query` filter hook, that will display only featured product in shop (but not in other archives pages):

```
// Display featured products in shop pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'custom_product_query_tax_query', 10, 2 );
function custom_product_query_tax_query( $tax_query, $query ) {
    if( is_admin() ) return $tax_query;

    if ( is_shop() ) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => 'featured'
        );
    }

    return $tax_query;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

Comment: Can you please update your answer, to include a pagination and a limit of 10 products per page?

Comment: @WooQA You should better ask a new question for that, as this is something different. Here I have just answered your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to override archive-product.php template to your theme file

then add below code to display featured product in shop pahe.

```
    <?php 
                          $meta_query  = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
                          $tax_query   = WC()->query->get_tax_query();
                          $tax_query[] = array(
                              'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                              'field'    => 'name',
                              'terms'    => 'featured',
                              'operator' => 'IN',
                          );

                          $args = array(
                              'post_type'           => 'product',
                              'post_status'         => 'publish',                          
                              'posts_per_page'      => '5',
                              'orderby'             => 'DESC',                          
                              'meta_query'          => $meta_query,
                              'tax_query'           => $tax_query,
                          );
                            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

                            if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                                  $id = $product->get_id();
                                  $image_sale = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $loop->post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
                                  $product_url = get_permalink($id);
                                  $product = wc_get_product($id);
                                  $product_title = $product->get_title();                              
                                  $sale_price =  $product->get_price();

                                  ?>

                     <div class="item">
                              <div class="product-box">
                                 <div class="product-img">
                              <a href="<?php echo $product_url;?>" title="" ><img src="<?php  echo $image_sale[0]; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>"></a>                                    
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="product-content">
                                    <h5><?php echo $product_title;?></h5> 
                                    <P>$<?php echo $sale_price;?>,00</P>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                         </div>


<?php 
            endwhile;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in your functions.php to display featured products in the shop page.

```
<?php 
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'ss_custom_product_query' );

function ss_custom_product_query( $q ){
    $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );
    if ( is_shop() ) {
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'   => '_featured',
            'value' => 'yes'
        );
    }
    $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
?>
```