# Make Featured column sortable in Woocommerce admin products list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

In WooCommerce backend on the productlist, we have the possibility to make a product featured by clicking on the star.

However, if you have a lot of products and you want to see afterwards which products are featured, we have to search through all products.

So I would like to make this column sortable so that all featured products are shown at the front or back during sorting

With my code I have so far, the column can be sorted, but the result becomes empty during sorting, resulting in 0 results

```
// 'featured' column sortable on the 'product' page
function sc_sortable_column( $columns ) {
     $columns['featured'] = 'featured';

     return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_sortable_columns', 'sc_sortable_column' );


// Orderby 'featured' (product)
function filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
     if( ! is_admin() )
         return;

     $orderby = $query->get('orderby');

     // featured, product
     if( $orderby == 'featured') {
         $query->set( 'meta_key', '_featured' );
         $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
     }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_pre_get_posts' );
```

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Ok

Answer (score 1):

Since WooCommerce 3, featured products are now handled by `product_visibility` custom taxonomy for the term `featured`. See: [Get WooCommerce featured products in a WP_Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46246614/get-woocommerce-featured-products-in-a-wp-query/46247028#46247028)

Normally **taxonomies doesn't allow posts to be sorted** as described in on this WordPress Development StackExchange thread: [Using wp_query is it possible to orderby taxonomy?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/using-wp-query-is-it-possible-to-orderby-taxonomy/).

But for example using the filter `posts_clauses` it's possible to sort products by featured.

So the code to be used will be:

```
// Make Product "Featured" column sortable on Admin products list
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_sortable_columns', 'products_featured_sortable_column' );
function products_featured_sortable_column( $columns ) {
     $columns['featured'] = 'featured';

     return $columns;
}

add_filter('posts_clauses', 'orderby_product_visibility', 10, 2 );
function orderby_product_visibility( $clauses, $wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $taxonomy  = 'product_visibility';
    $term      = 'featured';

    if ( isset( $wp_query->query['orderby'] ) && $term == $wp_query->query['orderby'] ) {
        $clauses['join'] .=<<<SQL
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID={$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} USING (term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} USING (term_id)
SQL;
        $clauses['where']   .= " AND (taxonomy = '{$taxonomy}' OR taxonomy IS NULL)";
        $clauses['groupby']  = "object_id";
        $clauses['orderby']  = "GROUP_CONCAT({$wpdb->terms}.name ORDER BY name ASC) ";
        $clauses['orderby'] .= ( 'ASC' == strtoupper( $wp_query->get('order') ) ) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
    }
    return $clauses;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this works great. Well it is to say, almost. The featured products are indeed shown at the top or at the bottom during sorting. However, not all products are displayed anymore during sorting. For example, variable products that are out of stock (not featured) are displayed. If they are back in stock, they will not be displayed during sorting. I have disabled all plugins I use except woocommerce but the problem still persists. 
I don't know if the problem is specifically related to in or out stock.

Comment: Does not work at all. Yes, it makeks featured column sortable, but does not sort by featured, plus unwanted filtering appears.