# WooCommerce make Categories column sortable on Product admin page

Tags: woocommerce

I want to make the Categories column sortable on the Product admin page that is here:

/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product

I had a real hard time figuring this out... there was not a lot of information on how to do it!

Simply adding add_filter manage_edit-product_sortable_columns was not sufficient.

See my answer below for solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing we do is make the Categories header at the top of the columns clickable for sorting using the filter manage_edit-product_sortable_columns

Then we need to actually sort the categories in the columns using the filter posts_clauses. This is actually pretty complicated and the answer in this linked post was very helpful (the code is basically copied and pasted with a few changes): [Make Featured column sortable in Woocommerce admin products list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63203760/make-featured-column-sortable-in-woocommerce-admin-products-list/63213063#63213063)

```
// make header of column clickable for sort
add_filter('manage_edit-product_sortable_columns', 'abcxyz_sortable_product_columns_header');
function abcxyz_sortable_product_columns_header( $sortable_columns ) {
    $sortable_columns['product_cat'] = 'product_cat';
    return $sortable_columns;
}

// sort the categories column when clicked
add_filter('posts_clauses', 'abcxyz_sortable_product_column_product_cat', 11, 2 );
function abcxyz_sortable_product_column_product_cat( $clauses, $wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $taxonomy  = 'product_cat';
    $term      = 'product_cat';
    if ( isset( $wp_query->query['orderby'] ) && $term == $wp_query->query['orderby'] ) {
        $clauses['join'] .=<<<SQL
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID={$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} USING (term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} USING (term_id)
SQL;
        $clauses['where']   .= " AND (taxonomy = '{$taxonomy}' OR taxonomy IS NULL)";
        $clauses['groupby']  = "object_id";
        $clauses['orderby']  = "GROUP_CONCAT({$wpdb->terms}.name ORDER BY name ASC) ";
        $clauses['orderby'] .= ( 'ASC' == strtoupper( $wp_query->get('order') ) ) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
    }
    return $clauses;
}
```